# What's the difference between: "I'm having a headache" and "I have a headache"?

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context, grammaticality, grammaticality-in-context

Is there any difference between the following sentences?

> 1 I'm **having** a headache.

> 2 I **have** a headache.

Comment: What do you think the difference is?

Comment: I think that, by using "have" instead of using "having" I am saying that it will happen again and by using "having" I focusing on when it is happening which is now, although I am not sure.

Comment: coolguy: Nah - it's nothing to do with "repetition". But the choice of verb form ***is*** much affected by whether the verb is ***stative*** or ***dynamic***.